# How to convert query string to hebrew letters

Tags: angular, unicode, hebrew

I have this line to get the query string from this url `http://localhost:4200/אבי`:

```js
const path = location.path(true); // returns "%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99"
```

Can I convert it back to normal hebrew letters (in this case `אבי`)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the global function `decodeURI`:

```js
console.log(decodeURI("%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99"));
```

There is a counterpart, `encodeURI` to make the opposite:

```js
console.log(encodeURI("אבי"));
```